# Change Content in Error Page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to build a chrome extension that blocks certain websites and shows you a customized error page, without changing the URL to something else.

there are two ways in my mind:

1. redirect to a customized HTML page, but after he re-direction, the URL changes to something like:

> chrome-extension://ffdbaonbaojnfenboneakifcelgocobb/mycustomizederrorpage.html

i am thinking if there is any way to disguise the url chagne?

2. use

> chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener

, but with this one the error page shows

> This webpage was blocked by an extension
>
> ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

The url remains as the site we blocked, but I failed to access/change the DOM element of this page.

Update:
as wOxxOm suggested, method 1 will not work. so how about method 2 - access the error page and change its html? is that something we can do?

Comment: The address box of Chrome always displays the actual url except for the new tab page so no,  there's nothing you can do.

Comment: then how about change the DOM of an error page?

Comment: No, Chrome doesn't allow changing its built-in pages.